# Looking for Windows shared web hosting with PHP support

Tags: web-hosting, php, asp.net, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for Windows based shared web hosting which supports multiple hosted web sites (multiple domains). Supported technologies should contain:

- ASP.NET 4, ASP.NET MVC
- IIS 7
- MS SQL 2008
- PHP, MySQL

It is for my hobby projects so it should not be too expensive.

I tried GoDaddy's Windows Deluxe hosting but the experience is very bad and I want to move elsewhere. WordPress hosted on GoDaddy's Windows hosting is unloaded every few minutes and next request takes around 20s to complete. Following request to empty site takes around 3s to complete. Even request for RSS which transfers 1.2KB takes several seconds. The delay happens in PHP processing because static content is served within 200ms. It helped to migrate to Linux hosting (all requests are served under 1s) but Linux hosting is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance and you have experience with installing / management server you should look at to [Rackspace Cloud Server](http://www.rackspacecloud.com) .

Comment: I don't need performance, I just want "common" response times. Cloud hosting is probably overkill for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eray, but I would suggest going with rackspacecloud sites instead.

How about [1and1](http://www.1and1.com)?

Comment: I checked 1and1 and it doesn't provide technologies I expect.

Comment: It seems to have everything aside from mentioning what version of IIS it is using. Did you get in touch with them to find out what IIS they're using?